# SQL query with DateTime does not respect timezone in ISO timestamp

Tags: android, sql, between

I have an sql lite database in Android with a timestamp column and I am querying for all values between two timestamps.

The timestamp is stored in this format: "2021-08-04T01:59:59+02:00" so it includes the timezone.

The problem is that for a query using BETWEEN, like this one:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + TIMESTAMP + " BETWEEN Datetime('" + startDate + "')" + " AND " + "Datetime('" + endDate + "')";
```

Where I want to get all the records for 24h
passing startDate = "2021-08-04T00:00:00+02:00"
and endDate = "2021-08-04T23:59:59+02:00"

I still get back a result with the timestamp at midnight the day before:
"2021-08-03T00:00:00+02:00"

If I adjust my startDate 2h into the future such as:
"2021-08-04T02:00:00+02:00"

Then it does work and the event with timestamp "2021-08-03T00:00:00+02:00" is no longer returned.

Also, if I just pass the day like:
startDate: 2021-08-04
endDate: 2021-08-05

Then it works and the event from August 3:rd is not returned so in that case, it appears SQL Datetime magically gets things right.

So, my assumption is that the formatting of my dates is not fully compatible with the Datetime by SQL used but I am not sure how to properly address the problem. Afaik the "2021-08-04T02:00:00+02:00" is a valid ISO format so I expected to be able to use it like in the Query above?

Update:
I have run another test today trying to use Datetime(TIMESTAMP) and also adding the modifier 'utc' to the Datetime since my timestamps are in localtime and according to this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

adding 'utc' should ensure the query converts them

Either way, I still face the same doubt.

I have an entry in the database with the timestamp "2021-08-04T00:00:00+02:00"

and when querying with startDate = "2004-08-04" and endDate = "2021-08-05" it does work and I get that record back.

However querying with startDate = "2021-08-04T00:00:00+02:00" and endDate = "2021-08-04T23:59:59+02:00" it does not. Not even after changing the SELECT query to use Datetime for the TIMESTAMP and adding 'utc' modifier like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + NAME + " LIKE " + "'" + name + "'"  + " AND Datetime('\" " + TIMESTAMP + "\"', 'utc')" + " BETWEEN Datetime('" + startDate + "', 'utc')" + " AND " + "Datetime('" + endDate + "', 'utc')
```

Comment: There is no DATETIME type in SQLite (so obviously it will work like `SELECT ... TEXT BETWEEN TEXT AND TEXT` )... so what is the type of TIMESTAMP and what are the values  ? ... if they are in ISO text then maybe you should try to use `Datetime(TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: Thanks @selvin for taking the time to comment. This is very likely due to poor understanding on my side. I have updated the question with the results from another test in case it helps.

Comment: prolly your data are different ... [as it's working fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=07789be4b6d4251510e501d47d0c3329)